# Unicode file with python and fileinput

Tags: python, utf-8

I am becoming more and more convinced that the business of file encodings is made as confusing as possible on purpose. I have a problem with reading a file in `utf-8` encoding that contains  just one line:

```
“blabla this is some text”
```

(note that the quotation marks are some *fancy* version of the standard quotation marks).

Now, I run this piece of `Python` code on it:

```
import fileinput
def charinput(paths):
    with open(paths) as fi:
        for line in fi:
            for char in line:
                yield char
i = charinput('path/to/file.txt')
for item in i:
    print(item)
```

with two results:
If i run my python code from command prompt, the result is some strange characters, followed by an error mesage:

```
ď
»
ż
â
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "krneki.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp852.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position
0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I get the idea that the problem comes from the fact that Python tries to read a "wrongly" encoded document, but is there a way to order `fileinput.input` to read `utf-8`?

---

EDIT: Some really weird stuff is happening and I have **NO** idea how any of it works. After saving the same file as before in `notepad++`, the python code now runs within IDLE and results in the following output (newlines removed):

```
ď»żâ€śblabla this is some textâ€ť
```

while I can get the command prompt to not crash if I first input `chcp 65001`. Running the file then results in

```
ÄÂ»Å¼Ã¢â‚¬Å›blabla this is some text Ã¢â‚¬Å¥
```

Any ideas? This is a horrible mess, if you ask me, but it is vital I understand it...

Comment: Tried changing the code page setting?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean by that?

Comment: You are running this from a windows shell?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham From a windows 7 command prompt, yes.

Comment: I don't use windows but I know there are problems with unicode and the windows shell. Try `chcp 65001` in shell

Comment: can you show me a couple of lines of you input file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I wrote my input file at the beginning of my question, it has only that line, so only `“blabla this is some text”`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham changed fileinput to open, same problem. Also, the command prompt now (after saving my file in notepad++) returns some characters and then crashes with a different message.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11544596/3218018 will be helpfull

Answer (score 14):

### Encoding

Every file is encoded. The byte 0x4C is interpreted as latin capital letter L according to the ASCII encoding, but as less-than sign ('<') according to the EBCDIC encoding. *There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.*

There are single byte character sets like ASCII that use a single byte to encode each symbol, there are double byte character sets like KS X 1001 that use two bytes to encode each symbol, and there are encodings like the popular UTF-8 that use a variable number of bytes per symbol.

UTF-8 has become the most popular encoding for new applications, so I'll give some examples: The [Latin Capital Letter A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/41/index.htm) is stored as a single byte: `0x41`. The [Left Double Quotation Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) (“) is stored as three bytes: `0xE2 0x80 0x9C`. The emoji [Pile of Poo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F4A9/index.htm) is stored as four bytes: `0xF0 0x9F 0x92 0xA9`.

Any program that reads a file and has to interpret the bytes as symbols has to know (or to guess) which encoding was used.

If you are not familiar with Unicode or UTF-8 you might want to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/unicode.html

### Reading Files in Python 3

Python 3's builtin function `open()` has an optional keywords argument `encoding` to support different encodings. To open a UTF-8 encoded file you can write `open(filename, encoding="utf-8")` and Python will take care of the decoding.

Also, the `fileinput` module supports encodings via the `openhook` keyword argument: `fileinput.input(filename, openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8"))`.

If you are not familiar with Python and Unicode or UTF-8 you should read http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html
I also found some nice tricks in http://www.chirayuk.com/snippets/python/unicode

### Reading Strings in Python 2

In Python 2 `open()` does not know about encodings. Instead you can use the `codecs` module to specify which encoding should be used: `codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8")`

The best source for Python2/Unicode enlightment is http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Regarding fileinput.input() you cannot combine openhook and inplace according to the python 3 docs. What if I need both because I want to change a file linewise whose encoding is not guessed/set.

Comment: @Timo I came here for the same reason and so far I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203040/combining-inplace-filtering-and-the-setting-of-encoding-in-the-fileinput-module) answer which suggests to just do it yourself

Comment: @lucidbrot [this](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/tess_md.py) is how I did it, so using `open` twice, for reading and wrting.